# XState: guard for finite number of retries

Tags: javascript, xstate

I have an `XState` state machine in JavaScript that is pretty simple; it initiates a connection to a server and on `FAILURE`, tries reconnecting. My objective is to do a finite number of retries (say, 3 times) after which it goes into final state.

I can't figure out how to achieve this. Any help is appreciated.

From my understanding, if the guard evaluates to `TRUE`, `TARGET` is transitioned to. What if the guard evaluates to `FALSE`? How do I transition to `TRIED_ENOUGH_TIMES_DONE`?

```
WAITFORRECONNECT: {
            //activities: ["showingLoadingPanel"],
            entry: (context, event) => {
                console.log("logging re-connect entry call");
                console.log('Retry Count: ' + context.iNumberOfRetries);
            },
            on: {
                DISCONNECTED: { target: 'showingAlert', actions: assign({ errorMessage: (context, event) => event.data }) },                    
                LOGIN_SUCCESS: 'IDLE',

                LOGIN_FAILURE: {
                    
                    actions: assign({ iNumberOfRetries: (context, event) => context.iNumberOfRetries + 1 }),                        
                    target:  'WAITFORRECONNECT',
                    cond: 'isMaxRetriesReached',
                    internal: false

                },
                LOGOUT: {
                    target: 'showingFinalAlert',
                    actions: assign({ errorMessage: (context, event) => event.data })
                },
                CLOSEWINDOW: {
                    target: 'showingFinalAlert',
                    actions: assign({ errorMessage: (context, event) => event.data })
                }
            },
            invoke: {
                src: (context, event) =>
                    connectToServer(
                        context.waitTimeInMilliSeconds,
                        context.sServerAddress,
                        context.sUsername,
                        context.sPassword,
                        context.sPort,
                    ),

                onError: {
                    target: "showingAlert",
                    actions: assign({ errorMessage: (context, event) => event.data })
                }
            },



        },       

    {
        activities: { showingLoadingPanel: createLoadingActivity },
        guards: { 
                isMaxRetriesReached: ({context}) =>
                    {                           
                        return context.iNumberOfRetries <=2;
                    }
            }

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified my LOGIN_FAILURE state to accomodate an IDLE transition if maxRetriesFails. This seems to be working.

```
LOGIN_FAILURE:              
                        
[
                        
{
    target:  'WAITFORRECONNECT',
    cond: 'isMaxRetriesReached',            

},
                        
{ target: 'IDLE'},
],
```